# Is $\int \exp(x \exp(x)) dx$ a well-known integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

Recently  puzzling around with the Lambert-$W$ function, I have become intrigued by the integrals:

$$\int e^{xe^{x}}dx \tag{1}$$

$$\int e^{xb^{x}}dx \tag{2}$$

$$\int e^{axb^{x}}dx \tag{3}$$

the latter two with $0 < b < 1$.

Are any of these *well-known* indefinite integrals with closed-form solutions?

Comment: No as far as I know. But proving my claim is a hard task. You can get an idea about such a proof from [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)